# Load an image from URL database

Tags: java, android, image, url, load

First code:

```
`db_img = Jasonobject.getString("image");
imagelink.setText(db_img);`
```

- The code above is grab the data from mysql database.
- "imagelink" is textview.
- The code will display the data into textview
- "image"from mysql is string because is url link.

Second code:

```
    new DownloadImageTask((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.qrimg)).
         execute("http://localhost/project/image/pic1.jpg");
```

- The second code is load the image base on the URL
- **My problem is how to pass the value from first code into .execute("HERE")**

**Code:**
`

```
EditText etacode;
EditText txtName;
Button btnscanitem;


//testing
TextView imagelink;

//hidden textview 
TextView texttime;
TextView textunit;
TextView textrm;
TextView textexp;
Button btnconfrim;

ImageView img;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.acode);

    btnscanitem = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnscanitem);
    etacode = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etacode);
    etacode.setVisibility(View.GONE);       


    //testing
    imagelink = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.imagelink);

    btnconfrim = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnconfrim);
    btnconfrim.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
    img.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    img.setImageResource(0);

}

class task extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void>
{
private ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(AcodeActivity.this);
    InputStream is = null ;
    String result = "";
    protected void onPreExecute() {
       progressDialog.setMessage("Fetching data...");
       progressDialog.show();
       progressDialog.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {
    public void onCancel(DialogInterface arg0) {
        task.this.cancel(true);
       }
    });
     }
       @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
      String url_select = "http://Localhost/getproduct.php";

      HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
      HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url_select);

          ArrayList<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        try {
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(param));

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

        //read content
        is =  httpEntity.getContent();                  

        } catch (Exception e) {

        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());

        }
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = "";
        while((line=br.readLine())!=null)
        {
           sb.append(line+"\n");
        }
            is.close();
            result=sb.toString();               

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                    Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
                }

            return null;

        }
    protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {

        // Fetch data from Json database
        try {
            JSONArray Jarray = new JSONArray(result);
            for(int i=0;i<Jarray.length();i++)
            {
            JSONObject Jasonobject = null;
            Jasonobject = Jarray.getJSONObject(i);


            String apromoid = Jasonobject.getString("aid");


            String db_img="";

            if(etcode.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(apromoid)) {



                db_img = Jasonobject.getString("image");
                imagelink.setText(db_img);


                String temp;
                temp = db_img;
                //String imagelink =  temp;
                //(db_img);


            break;
            }

            }
            this.progressDialog.dismiss();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
        }
    }
    }




@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.acodescanner, menu);
    return true;
}



public void onClick (View view){
    if(view.getId() == R.id.btnscanitem){
        IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
        integrator.initiateScan();


    }

}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
      IntentResult scanResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
      if (scanResult != null) {
        // handle scan result

          String acode;

          acode = scanResult.getContents();

          EditText etacode = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etacode);

          etacode.setText(acode);

          new task().execute();



          //String textlink = getimagelink;
          new DownloadImageTask((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.qrimg))
            .execute(db_img);



      }

}

private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
      ImageView bmImage;

      public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
          this.bmImage = bmImage;
      }

      protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
          String urldisplay = urls[0];
          Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
          try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
          } catch (Exception e) {
              Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
          return mIcon11;
      }

      protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
          bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
      }
    }
```

}
`

Comment: can you post some code ...

Comment: I don't have a complete code now. btw isit possible to pass the first code into temporary variable first and then pass into .execute("temp")?

Comment: Why can't you pass `db_img` to `execute()`?

Comment: sorry I'm newbie in java but I tried such as this `new DownloadImageTask((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.qrimg))
          .execute("db_img");`is not working

Comment: No no.. I meant `execute(db_img)` without quotes because it's a variable.

Comment: not able to run`.execute(db_img)`it sound like miss out the variable

Comment: Sorry im not able to post a picture to show u my problem. the problem is **db_img cannot be resolved to a varible**